# Creating Database and Table using php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, create-table

I want to insert form field values into a table 'company_details' inside DB 'B2B'.Trying to do thus with php mysqli connection. Database is created but table is not being created. Can anybody tell me what's the problem

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
    $servername="localhost";
    $username="root";
    $password="";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $conn->query("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B`"); 
    $sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B.company_details`(
                `comp_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                `company_name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
                `address` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
                `website` VARCHAR(70),
                `phone` VARCHAR(20),
                `mobile` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
                `fax` VARCHAR(20),
                `contact_person` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
                `deals_in` VARCHAR(300),
                `Introduction` VARCHAR(400),
                PRIMARY KEY (`email`));";
        if($conn->query($sql))
        {
            echo 'table is created succssfully';
        }
        function test_data($data)
        {
            $data=trim($data);
            $data=stripslashes($data);
            $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
            return $data;
        }
        $errors = array();
        if ( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] =="POST" )
        {
            $email=test_data($_POST["email"]);
            $password=test_data($_POST["password"]);
            $companyName=test_data($_POST["companyName"]);
            $introduction=test_data($_POST["introduction"]);
            $deals_in=test_data($_POST["deals_in"]);
            $address=test_data($_POST["address"]);
            $website=test_data($_POST["website"]);
            $phone=test_data($_POST["phone"]);
            $mobile=test_data($_POST["mobile"]);
            $fax=test_data($_POST["fax"]);
            $contact_person=test_data($_POST["contact_person"]);
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO company_details (company_name, address, email, mobile, contact_person, password, website, phone, fax, introduction, deals_in ) VALUES ( '".$companyName."', '".$address."', '".$email."', '".$mobile."', '".$contact_person."', '".$password."', '".$website."', '".$phone."', '".$fax."', '".$introduction."', '".$deals_in."')");
            echo 'Submitted Successfully';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<h2>Access is Denied</h2>';
        }
        $conn->close();
?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Select database before creating table.

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,"B2B");
```

Comment: That is also true, but since he chosen OO approach,  `$conn->select_db()` is more coherent with his code.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of reasons that your table may not be creating properly. The first error is in the table name line. You need to use backticks for the database name and for the table name.

Then, you have defined TWO primary keys. So assuming you don't want `email` to be a primary key too, this revised version of your code will work:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B`.`company_details` (
`comp_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`company_name` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`website` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`mobile` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`fax` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`contact_person` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`deals_in` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`introduction` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (`email`)
);
```

Comment: column 'email' needs to be primary key for me. Because its foreign key in another table. So i remove primary key from column 'comp_id' column. But it still not working.

i changed
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B.company_details`
to
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B`.`company_details`
and

`comp_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
to
`comp_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT,

BUT it's still not working.Help me.

Comment: You cannot define auto increment and NOT define the field as a primary key. For this code to work, you'll need to remove your AI from cust_id. I have revised my answer for you. 

You will need to auto increment your comp_id field manually.

Answer (score 0):

Before creating table you need to `use` database, like this:

```
$conn->select_db('B2B');
```

For more details, check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your code for create table. You mentioned 2 primary keys(email, comp_id) so that table didn't create

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `B2B.company_details`(
            `comp_id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            `email` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            `password` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            `company_name` VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL,
            `address` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
            `website` VARCHAR(70),
            `phone` VARCHAR(20),
            `mobile` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            `fax` VARCHAR(20),
            `contact_person` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            `deals_in` VARCHAR(300),
            `Introduction` VARCHAR(400));
```

Check with new code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you cannot have 2 primary keys in the same table.

Generally surrogate keys are a bad idea, and the foreign key constraint system ensures integrity on updates, so the circumstances where you do need to use them should be very rare.

What the other answers have wrong is that there is no requirement for a foreign key to reference a primary key. For INNODB, [it can reference any columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) declared in any index index:

> InnoDB permits a foreign key to reference any index column or group of columns. However, in the referenced table, there must be an index where the referenced columns are listed as the first columns in the same order.

For NDB it needs to be a unique index without additional columns.

Hence you simply need to replace

```
PRIMARY KEY (`email`));";
```

With

```
UNIQUE KEY `by_email` (`email`));";
```

Answer (score 0):

create table like this

```
function CreateTableNode (&$formvars) {
    $host = 'localhost';
    $database = 'test';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=test', $dbuser, $dbpass);



    $serialno = $formvars['serialno'];
    $qry =  "CREATE TABLE ".$serialno." ("."
            `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
            `humidity` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `temperature` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `gasquality` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
            `timestamp` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
        )";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($qry);
    $stmt->execute();
    $pdo = null;
    return true; 
}
```